# Does weapon rank affect stats in Max Payne 3 multiplayer?

Tags: max-payne-3

Does weapon rank affect weapon stats in Max Payne 3 multiplayer? I see there is dual wielding unlocks tied to weapon rank, but I can't tell if there are stats changes as well, e.g. damage, accuracy, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the weapons will have the same stats regardless of the rank.

The only thing you get from having certain weapon ranks are the different upgrades you can buy for them.